# Set custom Header in Request

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to send the following [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) with Javascript in an react-native environment:

```
>curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer <API-TOKEN>" 'https://api.mydomain.com/v1/foo/bar'
```

here is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://api.mydomain.com/v1/foo/bar',{
      headers: {
        "authorization": "Bearer exampleToken"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

on my iOS Device the screen is just blank, and I don't receive any error or logging message.

Running the curl command gives me the expected json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use in the following manner;

```
fetch('https://api.mydomain.com/v1/foo/bar', { 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': 'Bearer exampleToken'
   })
 });
```

Instantiating a `Headers` with each header key,value pair inside.

Comment: I also had `dataSource: responseJson.movies` but this api had no movie object. It works now!

Comment: it seems incomplete. Where does Headers come from?